# Unable to change presence status of my user with Smack

Tags: xmpp, smack

I tried to set online mode but it doesn't work through a Roster. I ran this code and check my localhost server, the mode still "available" and not "Do not disturb".

```
final Connection connection = new XMPPConnection("xxx.xxx.x.xx");

connection.connect();
connection.login("hieugioi@hieund", "123456");

final Roster roster = connection.getRoster();           
Presence p = roster.getPresence("hieugioi@hieund");
p.setPriority(128);
p.setMode(Mode.dnd);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because you don't send the Presence packet to the server. After you have assembled your Presence packet you need to send it. For example:

```
Presence p = new Presence(available, "I am busy", 42, Mode.dnd);
connection.sendStanza(p);
```

See also: [Smack - Getting Started; section "Reading and Writing Packets"](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/gettingstarted.html)

Comment: After setting it, I can't get it out. That's the problem. I expect a function like this: connection.getStatus(), connection.getMode();

Comment: hi @Flow ..I have tried this..But it is showing status of only online users..not for offline users?How to get status of all the offline , online users?